# TimeSpan.TotalSeconds string formatting

Tags: c#, string, formatting

I have two lines of code, both are outputting TimeSpans as TotalSeconds (or they should be)

```
 s.QuickestExecutionTime.TotalSeconds.ToString()

444.2573845

 s.AverageExecutionTime.TotalSeconds.ToString()

00:03:45.7616697
```

The FIRST is what I want and expect. Why the second???? It's formatted to hours, minutes, seconds.

Comment: `QuickestExecutionTime` and `AverageExecutionTime` both have same type ?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. I'd be *very* surprised to see that output assuming `AverageExecutionTime` is a `TimeSpan` - whereas if you'd just got `s.AverageExecutionTime.ToString()`, it would make sense. Perhaps you're running an old build?

Comment: What are the types of `QuickestExecutionTime` & `AverageExecutionTime`?

Comment: I guess `TotalSeconds` is a TimeSpan

Comment: Yes, both are TimeSpans.

Comment: And, Jon, you're not the only surprised. It's reproducible - this is an interface I've written for a client to interrogate a WCF service. They've noticed this "inconsistency"

Comment: Why would .ToString() be different between the two calls?

Comment: @Anant - yes both are identical - they measure how long an operation has taken to complete.

Comment: And @Jon, what I've provided IS the output from the interface- it's logged to a text file.

Comment: @MuckersMate if both have same Type then convert to string should return same String double check both type.

Comment: Thanks @Anant. But these are both Timespans. I've been working on this for the past couple of days - no closer to a solution, hence SO post.

Comment: Unfortunately while we don't have any more information, and no way of reproducing it (even if *you* have a way of reproducing it) it's going to be hard to help. Are you able to change the logging? If so, I would do so to make it *absolutely certain* that you're not misreading the log, e.g. that either two log entries are being concatenated, or you're reading that second log entry as if it were from the second piece of code when actually it's from a different log entry. Are you able to step through this in a debugger?

Comment: @Jon Unfortunately this is live on a client's site. The interface communications are logged to a Textbox (big, long string) - that's how I can provide the communications as they are provided. In my test environment, it all worked perfectly. But why would double.ToString() give 2 different formats? It's as if the second call is recognising the underlying datatype....

Comment: I very very much doubt that `double.ToString()` is *really* giving that output. I strongly suspect it's something unexpected going on in the logging code, but it's going to be very hard for us to work out.

Comment: SetArrayValue(result, (int)RecipeHeader.AverageExecutionTime + RECIPE_OFFSET, s.AverageExecutionTime.TotalSeconds.ToString());
                    

SetArrayValue(result, (int)RecipeHeader.QuickestExecutionTime + RECIPE_OFFSET, s.QuickestExecutionTime.TotalSeconds.ToString());

Identical code, identical data types